# PHP / MYSQL Not Returning Entire BLOB At Random

Tags: php, mysql

We have a large table (10M + rows), with two BLOB columns.  When checking certain entries with command line, the full contents are present, however using PHP to output the results, it cuts one of the BLOB fields short by about 200 characters or so at random.  I already changed the memory limit in PHP.ini to 1024MB.  Is there any other cap that I should be checking?

The exact same script pulling the exact same row causes the random string length to be output.  It's using a simple mysql_fetch_row() method.

Comment: Is it actually random, or are the same rows always truncated? Are you sure this is a truncate-on-read problem and didn't already occur at write time?

Comment: Please dont use [the `mysql_` database extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), it
is deprecated (gone for ever in PHP7) Specially if you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` database extensions.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) its really pretty easy

Comment: It is random to the point where the same row is being pulled up on refresh using the same script and sometimes the blob is complete, and sometimes it is not.  Which is why I initially thought it to be some sort of memory issue.  The actual blob size is around 16kb